# Automatically calculate overtime hours

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets to keep track of time with the bimonthly timesheet template. What would be useful is if the spreadsheet could start adding hours to another column when the total hours worked per day exceeds 10 hours.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by modifying the current formulas and adding one of your own.

Based on the template you mentioned, you need to amend the formula for the **Total hours per day:** column to:

`=IF(24*(C2-B2) > 10, 10, 24*(C2-B2))`

Then in Column E add a new formula:

`=IF(D2=10, ABS(10.00 - (24*(C2-B2))),0)`

Then the Formula for **Total Hours For This Pay Period** needs to be amended to include any hours over the 10 hour threshold.

`=SUM(D2:D16)+SUM(E2:E16)`

This will give you an output similar to the this:
[image: Google Spreadsheet Hours Worked]